# How is the translog cost function derived?

Tags: production-function, cost-functions

I realize that the translog production function is derived as a second order taylor approximation of a production function (e.g. the CES-production function), as explained in [this post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/26144/deriving-the-translog-production-function).

Is the translog *cost* function derived similarly as a taylor expansion of an arbitrary multiple product cost function? Or is it derived trough cost minimization of a translog *production* function? Or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not trivial (and maybe not even possible) to find the cost function corresponding to a translog production function. And this cost function corresponding to a translog production function has not a translog functional form.
If you rewrite a cost function as follow $c(w,y)=c(\exp(\ln w),\exp(\ln y)) =: C(\ln w,\ln y),$ then a second order Taylor development of $C$ around a reference point $(\ln w_0,\ln y_0)$ yields a translog cost function (after reparameterization).